# Firebase To know data added or removed for addValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase and I have written query like this. Problem is I don't know whether data is added or removed. How can I differentiate?

```
    Query queryRoom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Conversation").child(conversationID);

    queryRoom.keepSynced(true);

    queryRoom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
            if (conversation != null) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use childEventListener from firebase database docs, it has methods for child added, removed...events

Comment: That sounds like the start of a good answer @Andromeda. Feel like posting an expanded version of it as an answer, so that we can upvote/accept it?

Comment: @Khant: see the section on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) in the Firebase documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need you use `ChildEventListener` instead of `ValueEventListener` for differentiate the action. ChildEventListener is user trigger while any single child has added, remove, change, move and cancel.

While using a `ChildEventListener` is the recommended way to read lists of data, there are situations where attaching a `ValueEventListener` to a list reference is useful.

Attaching a `ValueEventListener` to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single `DataSnapshot`, which you can then loop over to access individual children.

You should get more information from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-types document.

***Like :***

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
        Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
        // comment and if so displayed the changed comment.
        Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
        String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
        // comment and if so remove it.
        String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        // A comment has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
        // displaying this comment and if so move it.
        Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
        String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load comments.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```